# Suitability of liquid plastic resin for plumbing application

Tags: everyday-chemistry, materials, plastics

Which synthetic resins are suitable for fabrication of plumbing components e.g pipe sections?

I'm trying to find an easy way to mold/house/encase a custom designed data logger.
The water temperature ranges between 10 to 50 degrees C.

EDIT: I'm planning this for both indoor & out door use. Under direct sunlight.

Answer (score 2):

Epoxy should work OK and you have different options that are easy to get.

Comment: Different options that are easier than resin casting?

Comment: You have puttys that you can shape by hand. I'm supposing a prototype so you might not need a mold.

Comment: How well do puttys handle UV/sunlight? I've always known putty to be a Terminal emulator [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) until I Googled.

Comment: I meant a dough you can give a shape to. Other forms are used for car paint and antiacid lining. I don't think you will have a problem with outdoor use.